# Why can use `&` and no use `and` with `np.where`?

Tags: python, numpy

I have faced a question which I can't deeply understand. Its bout **`numpy.where`** with concatenate operation.

There're no problem with: `np.where(a<b)`, but concatenate: `np.where(a<b and a<c)` can't be use, because `a<b and a<c` are not correct operation, where `a, b, c` - NumPy arrays. Its need to use: `a.any()` or `a.all()`.

[image]

But is **possible to use** bin concatenate **&**: `(a<c) & (b<c)` and `np.where((a<c) & (b<c))`.

My sample code is:

```
import numpy as np

a=np.random.rand(24)
b=np.random.rand(24)
print('numpy arr: a:',a,'numpy arr: b:',b,sep='\n',end='\n'*2)

x=np.where((a<.5) & (b<.5) & (a+b<.9))
print('np.where + &:',x,sep='\n',end='\n'*2)

x=np.where((a<.5) and (b<.5) and (a+b<.9))
print('np.where + and:',x,sep='\n',end='\n'*2)
```

Outs with error:

```
numpy arr: a:
[0.54537816 0.38319929 0.46888735 0.3094628  0.82972402 0.18391511
 0.42539084 0.94225313 0.084158   0.28709954 0.83255106 0.93719347
 0.8505356  0.97240065 0.04261917 0.680872   0.90600638 0.19259075
 0.97707041 0.71354481 0.85061694 0.37244139 0.86971696 0.16065248]
numpy arr: b:
[0.96636409 0.99881076 0.08200858 0.31301844 0.16029993 0.21851799
 0.96612466 0.2136599  0.83806977 0.88331435 0.49006737 0.96287388
 0.26380568 0.49451174 0.73109927 0.01291897 0.52652431 0.88284384
 0.46521207 0.32853427 0.70570596 0.04896036 0.19279199 0.79165465]

np.where + &:
(array([ 2,  3,  5, 21]),)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tim/1.py", line 10, in <module>
    x=np.where((a<.5) and (b<.5) and (a+b<.9))
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
>>>
```

Is it possible to use construction: `np.where((a<c) & (b<c))`, where `a, b, c` - NumPy arrays, or need to use `numpy.any` and `numpy.all` constructions?

Comment: Keep in mind that `where` just finds the `True` values in the argument.  So your question is just about the `(a<c)&(b<c)` part.  And each of those expressions has to be valid by itself.  Take a simple case, and evaluate the pieces with and without the `&`.

Comment: Another key point is that `and` is a python operation that only works with simple True/False values.  It's like the python `if`.  If `x<y` produces a numpy array, it won't work with `and` (or `if` or `or`).